# Could only be written to 0 of the 1 minReplication nodes. There are 3 datanode(s) running and 3 node(s) are excluded in this operation. Using docker

Tags: docker, hadoop, flume

I made a docker-compose.yml file that includes multiple apache services such as Hadoop, Kafka and Flume. Currently, I try to retrieve data with Kafka, send it to Flume (to be able to transform the data(structure), and store it inside the HDFS. I generate dummy data by using a Kafka producer where I can send messages to the Kafka broker. Flume listens to a certain topic, transforms and defines the location of the data, and tries to send it to the HDFS. Whenever the flume agent notices data is getting in, the following error occurs:

```
2021-11-14 20:16:13,554 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
2021-11-14 20:16:17,448 WARN hdfs.DataStreamer: Exception in createBlockOutputStream blk_1073742188_1365
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:672)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:946)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:206)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:586)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.createSocketForPipeline(DataStreamer.java:253)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.createBlockOutputStream(DataStreamer.java:1757)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.nextBlockOutputStream(DataStreamer.java:1711)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.run(DataStreamer.java:707)
2021-11-14 20:16:17,451 WARN hdfs.DataStreamer: Abandoning BP-2051009381-192.168.160.8-1635954925420:blk_1073742188_1365
2021-11-14 20:16:17,462 WARN hdfs.DataStreamer: Excluding datanode DatanodeInfoWithStorage[192.168.192.12:50010,DS-0eb49c38-45e0-46bb-be71-23f07b5ac9dc,DISK]
2021-11-14 20:16:28,525 WARN hdfs.DataStreamer: Exception in createBlockOutputStream blk_1073742189_1366
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:672)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:946)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:206)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:586)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.createSocketForPipeline(DataStreamer.java:253)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.createBlockOutputStream(DataStreamer.java:1757)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.nextBlockOutputStream(DataStreamer.java:1711)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.run(DataStreamer.java:707)
2021-11-14 20:16:28,525 WARN hdfs.DataStreamer: Abandoning BP-2051009381-192.168.160.8-1635954925420:blk_1073742189_1366
2021-11-14 20:16:28,533 WARN hdfs.DataStreamer: Excluding datanode DatanodeInfoWithStorage[192.168.192.10:50010,DS-829fd615-4b31-4379-874a-ad06769d138e,DISK]
2021-11-14 20:16:29,557 WARN hdfs.DataStreamer: Exception in createBlockOutputStream blk_1073742190_1367
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:672)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:946)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:206)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:586)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.createSocketForPipeline(DataStreamer.java:253)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.createBlockOutputStream(DataStreamer.java:1757)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.nextBlockOutputStream(DataStreamer.java:1711)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.run(DataStreamer.java:707)
2021-11-14 20:16:29,557 WARN hdfs.DataStreamer: Abandoning BP-2051009381-192.168.160.8-1635954925420:blk_1073742190_1367
2021-11-14 20:16:29,569 WARN hdfs.DataStreamer: Excluding datanode DatanodeInfoWithStorage[192.168.192.11:50010,DS-3c3a744b-d53c-4cb5-97ac-4dd3e128f6a7,DISK]
2021-11-14 20:16:29,588 WARN hdfs.DataStreamer: DataStreamer Exception
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.IOException): File /kafka/last-test-5/14-11-21/sensor-data.1636917373340.tmp could only be written to 0 of the 1 minReplication nodes. There are 3 datanode(s) running and 3 node(s) are excluded in this operation.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager.chooseTarget4NewBlock(BlockManager.java:2219)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirWriteFileOp.chooseTargetForNewBlock(FSDirWriteFileOp.java:294)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:2789)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.addBlock(NameNodeRpcServer.java:892)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:574)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:528)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:1070)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:999)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:927)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1730)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2915)

    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getRpcResponse(Client.java:1573)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1519)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1416)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine2$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine2.java:242)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine2$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine2.java:129)
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy14.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:530)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:165)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:157)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invokeOnce(RetryInvocationHandler.java:95)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:359)
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy15.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream.addBlock(DFSOutputStream.java:1084)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.locateFollowingBlock(DataStreamer.java:1898)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.nextBlockOutputStream(DataStreamer.java:1700)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.run(DataStreamer.java:707)
2021-11-14 20:16:29,590 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: Error while syncing
```

The data is written to the HDFS but the generated file(s) have a size of 0 byte and there is no content in the files available.

Does anyone know what causes this error and how to fix it?

Docker images used for this project:

- bde2020 (for Hadoop)
- bitnami (for Kafka & Zookeeper)

To reproduce this issue I created a git repo where you can pull the project to recreate the error, https://github.com/Benjaminbakir/Big-data-test

You will have to install Flume on your local machine as well to run the agent.conf file.

The file can be runned with the command (you will have to cd to the directory where the config file is stored): flume-ng agent -c . -f agent.conf --name agent -Xmx512m

Finally, you need to add the following to your etc/hosts file:

- 127.0.0.1    localhost namenode datanode1 datanode2 datanode3
- ::1              localhost namenode datanode1 datanode2 datanode3

When you now send a message with a Kafka producer to a topic named "test" the error should show up.

Command to create a Kafka topic: /opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic test --partitions 3 --replication-factor 1

Command to create a producer: $KAFKA_HOME/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list kafka:9092 --topic=test

Please let me know if anything is not clear enough, I will try to explain it more in detail then.

PS: The hadoop cluster is healthy, the datanodes and namenode are running and the user can download/upload files manually via the Hadoop web UI, but when data is send via Kafka & Flume this error occurs.

Comment: Your error says `There are 0 datanode(s) running`, but you modified it for the question title, so which is it?. Also, you should not be touching your hosts file

Comment: Secondly, Flume is basically very old way of doing this... Try using Kafka Connect, Nifi, or Apache Gobblin instead

Comment: Thank you for your comment, the error is how it is described in the title, I will modify the error log. I will have a look at your other suggestions in the meantime.

Comment: Look at the lines `Excluding datanode...` What address is `192.168.192.11:50010`? Is that a Docker container? If so, have you forwarded port 50010? Looking at your repo, doesn't look like you have

Comment: Yes, the port is forwarded in the hadoop.env file, the reason for this is because someone online mentioned this port is for data transfer and won't be blocked by the firewall, this didn't solve anything and can be set back to the original 9866 port. The address 192.168.xxx.xx is a private local address created by docker

Comment: It's not possible to forward ports from an env file. That's for defining environment variables only. Yes it's for data transfer. Flume is doing data transfer

Answer (score 2):

you just need to do some "port proxy",like forwarding ip:port to other_ip:port